# Custom sorting with multiple filed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var arr = [
    0:{region:2, saved: false, damage:-1}
    1:{region:1, saved: true, damage:2}
    2:{region:1, saved: false, damage:-1}
    3:{region:1, saved: true, damage:4}
    4:{region:2, saved: true, damage:3}
    5:{region:-1, saved: false, damage:-1}
    6:{region:3, saved: false, damage:-1}
];
```

I need to apply sorting like first with the region (increment order), within the same region unsaved comes first, after that as per the damage in **decremented** order.

Output should be like this

```
    arr =[0:{region:-1, saved: false, damage:-1}
 1:{region:1, saved: false, damage:-1}
 2:{region:1, saved: true, damage:4}
3:{region:1, saved: true, damage:2}
4:{region:2, saved: false, damage:-1}
5:{region:2, saved: true, damage:3}
6:{region:3, saved: false, damage:-1}];
```

Please help with a sort function in JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, have tried something like this but it works only till few items                               
 var sorted = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
                    
                    if (a.region === b.reason) {
                        if (!a.saved) return 1;

                        if (a.saved === b.saved) { return b.damage - a.damage; }
                        else if (!a.saved) return 1;
                        else return -1;
                   }
                   else return -1;
                
                }.bind(this));

Comment: You can simply use a OR condition @ShaileeRawat

Comment: @Ankit agarwal Can you provide any sample code.

Comment: @ShaileeRawat check the answer. I have posted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `OR` condition in your `Array.sort()` function:

```js
var arr= [
  {region:2, saved: false, damage:-1},
  {region:1, saved: true, damage:2},
  {region:1, saved: false, damage:-1},
  {region:1, saved: true, damage:4},
  {region:2, saved: true, damage:3},
  {region:-1, saved: false, damage:-1},
  {region:3, saved: false, damage:-1}
];
arr.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.region - b.region || a.saved - b.saved || b.damage - a.damage;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: One correction here in the output arr =[0:{region:-1, saved: false, damage:-1}
 1:{region:1, saved: false, damage:-1}
 2:{region:1, saved: true, damage:4}
3:{region:1, saved: true, damage:2}
4:{region:2, saved: false, damage:-1}
5:{region:2, saved: true, damage:3}
6:{region:3, saved: false, damage:-1}];

Comment: Does your input array has `key` 0, 1, 2? @ShaileeRawat

Comment: No, Just showing the index values

Comment: So, that index value is only when you check in console so why do you need that in output? @ShaileeRawat

Comment: can you please check the correction in output required, damage should be in decrements order  i.e damage 4 comes first then damage 2 for region=1

Comment: @ShaileeRawat cool. It's just to change `b.damage - a.damage` check the updated answer above.

Comment: Also -> `within the same region unsaved comes first`  IOW:, I think the OP wants `saved = false` coming before `saved = true`

Comment: @Keith nothing has been mentioned for `saved` property. That might be just an example

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal  It might not be obvious, but the quoted text is what the OP said..

Comment: @ankit saved= false should always comes first

Comment: @Keith, yes you are correct , requirement is the same. Unsaved should comes first

Comment: @ShaileeRawat  You should be able to add `|| a.saved - b.saved`, between the current ones.  This will work because `(false - true) === -1`  `(true - false) === +1` etc.

Comment: @ShaileeRawat edited the answer. Should be perfect now

Comment: @ShaileeRawat did that work?

Comment: @Keith ,Thank you it is working fine;

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal thankyou it is working fine.

Comment: @ShaileeRawat glad to help